# How to share someone's post using Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

My Facebook App posts messages on user wall. I want to share this messages on my wall, same as I click share action under user message. How can I do it using Facebook Graph API?

Comment: Notice: Posting messages to timeline isn't supported anymore. The only supported type of posting is posting to pages. I am using v3.2.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can share using the graph2 api. The way you do it is to use `/feed` edge and pass the post's url that you want to share as the link.

```
POST /v2.2/{page-id}/feed HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

link=https://www.facebook.com/{page_id}/posts/{post_id}
```

Standard Fb permissions to the post you are sharing do apply.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed

This was done today, in a local rails app, using FbGraph2 gem, with the above method.
[image]

Comment: ! You're a hero! how did you conclude that? The API is cryptic and completely unclear about this! Thanks!! I am on this for a while now, and nothing seemed to work. Could you tell about the process of reaching that solution?

Comment: @IbrahimShendy how did you do it ?

Comment: @Mathematics what did you try so far? can you upload your code and show me what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/post#readperms) for accessing posts via the API, it would appear that you cannot do this as it would require accessing the post of another user's timeline that you don't have permissions/an access token for.

*Edit* From further reading of the documentation you definitely cannot do this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/sharedposts#publish