# sharing object in facebook graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sharing

Im trying to share a facebook object using the graph API, but I donn't find how.
Im looking for something similiar to like operation, https://graph.facebook.com/OBJ_ID/likes? using HTTP_POST.
Anyone knows how I can do that?

Thx.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to do the same behavior of the share button on facebook, in a publication u can do 3 actions (reply, like and share), I want to make a share with my app.

Comment: I guess you are talking of [feed dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: No, with this link (if im not worng) u post a new message with a new content, what I want to do if sharing a facebook message (status, someone new photo, ...), like if u use the share button inside facebook.

Comment: Ohk got it. This isnt available in API. But you can use feed to post that feed after fetching it with `GET: /POT_ID`

Comment: Thx, I thought that, u can't make the share behavior. I think I can emulate it by posting a link to the facebook object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share someone's post using Facebook Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307262/how-to-share-someones-post-using-facebook-graph-api)