# how do i share a post on facebook using restfb

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

this is my java code using resfb lib to post something on my facebook groups feed:

```
FacebookClient fb=new DefaultFacebookClient(token);
FacebookType message=fb.publish(pid+"/feed",FacebookType.class,Parameter.with("message", description));
```

now what do i do to share posted article?

thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Have your actual FB user share the post on the page so that it appears on the user's timeline as well?

Comment: yeap, that what i want! i need link to the post appears on the user timeline.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to share someone's post using Facebook Graph API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307262/how-to-share-someones-post-using-facebook-graph-api)

Answer (score 1):

Graph API doesn't provide an explicit share operation, but you can create a post which is a link to another post, which should be displayed as a share. Something like this:

```
fb.publish("me/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("link", "https://www.facebook.com/10152237769155733"));
```

Comment: In my case it doesn't recognize the method "with" it is red underlined saying that this method is undefined for the type Parameter!