# Sharing a post on facebook page using RestFB

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm using RestFB to automatically post to a Facebook page (not my personal page, an entertainment news page I've set up)
I took the code example from here: [how do i share a post on facebook using restfb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177660/how-do-i-share-a-post-on-facebook-using-restfb) but it's not working for certain posts.
Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class FacebookHelper {

    private static final DefaultFacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("<access token>", Version.VERSION_2_5);
    private static final Page page = facebookClient.fetchObject("<page id>", Page.class);

    public static void updateStatus(String message, String link) {

        facebookClient.publish("<page id>/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", message), Parameter.with("link", link));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // not working - only message appearing in status
        FacebookHelper.updateStatus("RestFB test2", "https://www.facebook.com/becky.ofarrell.5/videos/1123590904340401/");
        // working correctly - message and photo in status
        FacebookHelper.updateStatus("RestFB test3", "https://www.facebook.com/mullingar.parish/photos/a.341019462759743.1073741826.341019429426413/431550013706687/?type=3");
        // working correctly - message and video in status
        FacebookHelper.updateStatus("RestFB test4", "https://www.facebook.com/RuairiOgclg/videos/574647342685093/");

    }

}
```

All links are public, so I don't think I'm breaking any privacy issues about using them here
For the example that's failing, I can share it manually without any problems

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have resolved itself, and posts are now being shared correctly. 
One theory is that the posts that failed to share were created before the access token I was using.
Either way, it's not an issue any more