# Sharing or linking post using Facebook Graph API on windows forms app

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am extending social media integration onto an app.

Found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307262/how-to-share-someones-post-using-facebook-graph-api) but no suitable answer.

**In a nutshell:**

1. **Post photo onto user1's wall (after they have logged in).**
2. **"Share" the post user2's wall (after they have logged in).**

I need to be able to login and upload photos to the account that I am currently logged in with.(I have achieved this).

I think this is the logic required:

Retrieve the post_id and share/post it onto another users timeline...
I have got it all working up to and including retrieving the post_id.
Now I am stuck and I can't seem to find a solution, maybe its just been a long week...

It is a windows forms app (don't judge - not my call) and I generate login using this code:

```
    public static string GenerateLoginUrl()
    {
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.client_id = ""; //app id
        parameters.redirect_uri = "https://www.google.com"; 
        parameters.response_type = "token";
        parameters.display = "popup";

        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        Uri loginUri = fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
        return loginUri.AbsoluteUri;
    }
```

Which I then Validate after Navigating to the above URL using this:

```
    private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (webBrowser1.Visible)
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient();
            FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
            if (fb.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Url, out oauthResult))
            {
                if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
                {
                    //happy
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I retrieve post_id on the "PostCompleted" method of the FacebookClient class instance as follows:

```
 fb.PostCompleted += (oo, eee) =>
    {
        if (eee.Cancelled || eee.Error != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var result = eee.GetResultData();
        JsonObject myObj = (JsonObject)result;
        string post_id = myObj["post_id"].ToString();
    };
```

I have managed to do all the little bits and pieces, but now I am stuck on bringing it together, thank you in advance, any information and helpful links would be great please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working to meet my requirements...

**NOTE:** This answer assumes you understand the basics of authenticating and posting using the C# Facebook API:

```
fb.PostCompleted += (o, ee) =>
    {
        if (ee.Cancelled || ee.Error != null)
            return;

        JsonObject myObj = (JsonObject)ee.GetResultData();
        string href = String.Format("https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid={0}&set=a.{1}", myObj["id"].ToString(), myObj["post_id"].ToString());

        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
        {
            ClientLogin loginDialog = new ClientLogin(href);
            loginDialog.Show();
        }));
    };
fb.PostTaskAsync(parameters);
```

Once the task completes, I open a form that contains a "WebBrowser" control 
where I call the following code:

```
webBrowserOAuth.Navigate(String.Format(@"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id={0}&href={1}&redirect_uri={2}", app_id, _href, redirect_uri));
```

Then handle the `"webBrowserOAuth_Navigated"` event to meet your requirements...